# xamarin Forms: Set Title of page at center of Navigation bar and add icon to the left side of the navigation bar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I am not using master detail page. I wish to set the title of page at the center of navigation bar. In `ios` it comes at center by default but not in `android`. Also I need to set a hamburger icon at left side of navigation bar as toolbar-item. How can I customize this behavior for both `Android` and `IOS`. My application has further detail pages  with navigation, so I want this behavior throughout my app.

Comment: I think you will need to use a custom NavigationPageRenderer. See SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499344/xamarin-forms-custom-android-navigationpagerenderer-title-and-subtitle/38515463 and the answer from @jimmgarr

Comment: It means that it can't be possible without custom Renderer , Very sad :(